# How to return a value after `retryWhen` expires? (for `canActivate` guard)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-ui-router, canactivate

When I reload my page, it always goes to blank page instead of the same page. The reason behind this is canActivate method which is cheking for user's permission gets invoked as soon as user refreshes the page and it is not able to get user data immediately. User data comes after some seconds.

I figured out that I can use `retryWhen` in the subscription, so the call is retried 3 times and if it doesn't complete, I can call the `navigateToNoAccessArea()` function.

The functions are the following:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):         
     Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree 
  {
    return this.getUserData(route);
   
  }
```

```
  private getUserData(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.userService.getUserData()
      .pipe(
        map(userData => {
          // If userData is empty, it returns an error (and catched in retryWhen)
          if(userData === null) throw new Error('User Data not initialized');
          return userData;
        }),
        // when no data is present, it retries the subscription (up to 3 times)
        retryWhen(err => err.pipe(delay(1000), take(3),
          finalize(()=> {
          //   this is called after it fails 3 times
          //   return does not work
            this.navigateToNoAccessArea();
            return false;
          })
        )),
        map(userData=> {
          // this map is called when data is got (if the retry fails 3 times it is skipped)
          // ***Some data manipulation is done here and true or false is returned ***
        }),
      )
  }
```

I should somehow return `false` if the retry fails 3 times (so `canActivate()` doesn't error out with `EmptyErrorImpl {message: 'no elements in sequence', name: 'EmptyError'}`. The redirection to the No Acess Area is working.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
retryWhen(err =>{ 
let flag = true;
err.pipe(delay(1000), take(3),
          finalize(()=> {
          //   this is called after it fails 3 times
          //   return does not work
            this.navigateToNoAccessArea();
            flag=false;
          });
return flag;
        )),
```